# Writing Printed Output to CSV - Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy

I want this output written via CSV

> ['https://www.lendingclub.com/loans/personal-loans' '6.16% to 35.89%']
>   ['https://www.lendingclub.com/loans/personal-loans' '1% to 6%']
>   ['https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans' '6.99% to 24.99%']
>   ['https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans' '6.99% to 24.99%']
>   ['https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans' '6.99% to 24.99%']
>   ['https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans' '6.99% to 24.99%']
>   ['https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans' '6.99% to 24.99%']
>   ['https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/' '6.99% to 24.99%']

However when I run the code to write the output to CSV I only get the last line written to the CSV file:

> ['https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/' '6.99% to 24.99%']

Could it be because my printed output is not comma separated? I attempted to circumvent having to put a comma in there by using a space as the delimiter. Let me know your thoughts. Would love some help on this because I am having the hardest time reshaping this collected data.

```
plcompetitors = ['https://www.lendingclub.com/loans/personal-loans',
                'https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans',
                'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/']

#cycle through links in array until it finds APR rates/fixed or variable using regex
for link in plcompetitors:
    cdate = datetime.date.today()
    l = r.get(link)
    l.encoding = 'utf-8'
    data = l.text
    soup = bs(data, 'html.parser')
    #captures Discover's rate perfectly but catches too much for lightstream/prosper
    paragraph = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('[0-9]%'))
    for n in paragraph:
        matches = re.findall('(?i)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*(?:to|-)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%', n.string)
        try:
            irate = str(matches[0])
            array = np.asarray(irate)
            array2 = np.append(link,irate)
            array2 = np.asarray(array2)
            print(array2)
            #with open('test.csv', "w") as csv_file:
            #    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=' ')
            #    for line in test:
            #        writer.writerow(line)
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to using csv file, pandas comes handy.

```
import datetime
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import numpy as np
import regex as re
import pandas as pd

plcompetitors = ['https://www.lendingclub.com/loans/personal-loans',
                'https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans',
                'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Link':[],'APR Rate':[]})
#cycle through links in array until it finds APR rates/fixed or variable using regex
for link in plcompetitors:
    cdate = datetime.date.today()
    l = r.get(link)
    l.encoding = 'utf-8'
    data = l.text
    soup = bs(data, 'html.parser')
    #captures Discover's rate perfectly but catches too much for lightstream/prosper
    paragraph = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('[0-9]%'))
    for n in paragraph:
        matches = re.findall('(?i)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*(?:to|-)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%', n.string)
        irate = ''
        try:
            irate = str(matches[0])
            df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Link':[link],'APR Rate':[irate]})
            df = pd.concat([df,df2],join="inner")
        except IndexError:
            pass
df.to_csv('CSV_File.csv',index=False)
```

I have stored each link and it's irate value in a data frame `df2` and I concatenate it to parent data frame `df`.
At the end, I write parent data frame `df` to a csv file.

Comment: Clever way of going about this. I kept trying to put everything in the same dataframe in a previous iteration of code and couldn't get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are opening the file in write-mode (the `"w"` in `open('test.csv', "w")`), meaning that Python overwrites what's already written in the file. I think you're looking for append-mode:

```
# open the file before the loop, and close it after
csv_file = open("test.csv", 'a')             # change the 'w' to an 'a'
csv_file.truncate(0)                         # clear the contents of the file
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=' ') # make the writer beforehand for efficiency

for n in paragraph:
    matches = re.findall('(?i)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*(?:to|-)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%', n.string)
    try:
        irate = str(matches[0])
        array = np.asarray(irate)
        array2 = np.append(link,irate)
        array2 = np.asarray(array2)
        print(array2)

        for line in test:
            writer.writerow(line)

    except IndexError:
        pass

# close the file
csv_file.close()
```

If this doesn't work, please let me know!

Comment: Switching it to 'a' worked and is adding all the lines; however, it's now parsing each character with a space between it now. Ex: h t t p s : / / w w w . l e n d i n g c l u b . c o m / l o a n s / p e r s o n a l - l o a n s
6 . 1 6 % " " t o " " 3 5 . 8 9 %

Comment: I don’t work with csv files often, but my guess would be that that is caused by the delimiter parameter on line 4. Try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: Turning a string into a list will split it into characters, e.g. `' '.join(list('abc'))`.